# How to use ref variable outside calling method in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference

How can I use ref variable outside the calling method in C#.

I will explain what I would like to acheive.

I have a method inside a class(MyClass), which looks like

```
private MyObject myobj;
public ref MyObject GetMyObject()
{
    return ref myobj;
}
```

Now I am fetching the variable inside another method from different class(FetchClass)

```
private MyObject fetchObj;
void Start()
{
    fetchObj = ref MyClass.instance.GetMyObject(); //getting error here
}
```

I like to use fetchObj in different method in the same class. Thats the reason I have declared outside.
But I am getting error in Start method.

Comment: Is there any pattern to acheive the similar use case?
I dont want to call GetMyObject everytime.

Comment: Create instance of your class as: `MyClass myClass= new MyClass()` then call your method as: `myClass.GetMyObject`

Comment: Do you just want to update properties of that object, or also replace it with a new object?

Comment: @Sh.Imran "ref keyword can be used only in methods' parameters" that is [not true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values)

Comment: @SayantanMandal is `MyObject` is actually an object(class)? If yes, I'm not sure why do you need `ref` here.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I have another method inside FetchClass which will run every second. and that method will print the current values inside MyObject.

Comment: @GuruStron MyObject is not passed as reference. Else I have to call GetMyObject() everytime to access updated variable inside that Object.

Comment: @SayantanMandal And what is the problem with calling it everytime? You can use property like `private MyObject fetchObj => MyClass.instance.GetMyObjectNotByRef()` to make this more convenient.

Comment: AFAIK ref methods return values can be assigned only to a _ref local_ variable not to a class level variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals

Comment: @GuruStron Calling everytime may be a overhead for a method. also it will be hard to maintain code if there is any change in reference in future.

Comment: @SayantanMandal In most cases it will be negligible overhead and I would say that the maintenance will be the same  as with your attempted approach.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks, that worked for me!! Could you put that as answer? I am from Java background, I have to see how that worked :)

Comment: @SayantanMandal done. Was glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `MyObject` is a class you can use an [expression bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) read-only property:

```
private MyObject fetchObj => MyClass.instance.GetMyObjectNotByRef();
```